# JMeter: Check JS return variable in Response Assertion

Tags: jmeter, response

I have around 20000 URLs and I need to find out few JS variables which can be retrieved on page load only.

I am going to paste all those URLs in a csv file and use JSR223 PreProcessor. This code I have checked and it is working fine but **how to use its return value in Response Assertion?**

[image]

**Update: This is what I tried, after below answer but it is not working**

Here in HTTP Request, I am hitting "www.msn.com" which give origin value as "https://www.msn.com". However, when I check in response it shows response is null.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your function does nothing as [Oracle Nashorn](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) engine doesn't have access to [`window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), you can check [jmeter.log](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) file yourself

[image]

Looking into [location.origin property description](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_origin.asp)

> Return the protocol, hostname and port number of a URL

So I would recommend the following:

1. Change the language to `groovy`
2. Change your script to

   ```
   vars.put('origin', prev.getURL().getProtocol() + '://' + prev.getURL().getHost() + ':' + prev.getURL().getPort())
   ```

   where `prev` stands for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) instance

Comment: How to get other JS variables apart from origin e.g. `window.kickfire` , `window.localstorage` etc?

Comment: You don't have `window` in JMeter as JMeter is not a browser. Consider going for [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) if you have to collect information using JavaScript.

Comment: You need to invoke [`WDS.browser.executeScript()` function](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) like `var formTypeIs=WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.origin"); WDS.vars.put('origin', originIs)`. See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/) article for more details

Comment: Updated as `WDS.browser.get("${rows}");
var originIs=WDS.browser.executeScript("function getOriginType() {" + "var getOriginType= window.origin;" + "return originType ;" + "}"+ "return getOriginType();");
WDS.vars.put('origin', originIs);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();` and then used in Response Assertion as shown in screenshot of Respnse Assertion, but it is giving error `Response was null`